# Installing a sill plate on a crawlspace for a manufactured home. Does it matter if I use spf white wood or treated?

Tags: concrete, wood

What type of wood should be used on a 8 inch cement block wall crawl space for a manufactured home. Spf white wood because of the metal I beams or treated lumber.

Comment: A 2 x 8 will be used for a sill plate. Should sill plate be SPF whitewood or treated.

Comment: It has been 45 years since I lived in a mobile home so my memory is fading, but IIRC . . . I  would say use treated wood. It is outside and exposed so white wood would be susceptible to attack.

Answer (score 1):

For wood in contact with masonry or concrete, the Code requires the use of an approved species and grade of wood such as decay resistant heartwood of Redwood, Black Locust, or Cedar or pressure treated in accordance with AWPA (See ICC R319.1) in areas subject to decay damage according to Table R301.2(1).

In the U.S., all but the very very most southern portion of the continental U.S. and Hawaii show as “severe” or “moderate”. The remainder shows as “negligible”. I’d consult with your local Building Department if your within that area.

The Code also allows the use of untreated lumber if separated by an approved moisture barrier. (Technically I guess the wood is not “in contact” with masonry or concrete with a moisture barrier.)

Answer (score 0):

Treated wood and a sill barrier / foam is also required to prevent the wood from wicking moisture into the wood. This stuff is really cheap and also used as an air seal barrier on homes.